# Undefined method `max_people' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a checkin, after submit, it said that "undefined method `max_people` for nil:NilClass"

**checkin.rb:**

```
class Checkin < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payment, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :service_items, dependent: :destroy

  before_save :calculate_price

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room

  validates :contact_name, presence: true
  validates :contact_phone, presence: true, numericality: true, length: {maximum: 11, minimum: 8}
  validate :check_num_guest

  enum status: [:waiting_pay, :paid, :accept, :reject]

  scope :order_desc, ->{order created_at: :desc}

  def calculate_price
    self.total_price = self.total_price -
     self.total_price * self.room.discount / 100
  end

  private
  def check_num_guest
    if self.num_guest > self.room.max_people
      errors.add :checkin, I18n.t("errors.num_people")
    end
  end
end
```

**checkins_controller.rb:**

```
class CheckinsController < ApplicationController
  load_resource :room

  def index
    @checkins = Checkin.order_desc.paginate page: params[:page]

  end

  def create
    @checkin = Checkin.new checkin_params
    @checkin.status = Checkin.statuses[:waiting_pay]
    if @checkin.save
      @payment = Payment.new
      flash[:success] = t "flash.checkins.checkin_success"
      render "payments/new"
    else
      @supports = Support::RoomSupport.new room: @room
      flash[:danger] = t "flash.checkins.create_checkin_fail"
      render "rooms/show"
    end
  end

  def show
    @payment = Payment.new
  end

  def update
    if @checkin.update_attributes checkin_params
      flash[:success] = t "flash.checkins.checkin_canceled"
    else
      flash[:danger] = t "flash.checkins.checkin_cancel_fail"
    end
    redirect_to checkins_path
  end

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    flash[:danger] = t "flash.rooms.room_not_found"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
  def checkin_params
    params.require(:checkin).permit :user_id, :num_guest, :contact_name, :contact_phone, :contact_address, :contact_email, :description, :total_price, :is_cancel, :status, :fromdate, :todate
  end
end
```

**Table room:**

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.string :number
      t.boolean :status, default: true
      t.float :price
      t.string :picture
      t.string :description
      t.integer :max_people
      t.string :facilities
      t.datetime :deleted_at
      t.integer :discount
      t.belongs_to :room_type, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `check_num_guest` validation tries to call the room relation but since you don't assign any room to the checkin `#room` returns `nil`.

You have to set the room of the checkin. But I would recommend you anyway to transform the validation to return if no room is set. The presence validator is responsible for unset values.

Something like this:

```
def check_num_guest
  return unless self.room.present?
  if self.num_guest > self.room.max_people
    errors.add :checkin, I18n.t("errors.num_people")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank so much- Tobias. I understood.

Comment: @AnhKieu good :) Would be cool if you'd mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: I marked, but system said something, I cannot mark. :(((.